# Put ViewStub below listView

Tags: java, android, listview, viewstub

I'm programming for Android 2.2 (API level 8) and in my main View I have, in a simplified way, this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      ...

    </TableRow>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/includeIdForPlayerStub"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/playerStubId"
            android:layout="@layout/player_stub" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to put the ViewStub in the bottom of the parent, right below the listview, but as it is now it doesn't work. The LinearLayout added by ViewStub sits in the bottom of the screen, but the list goes below the added content, causing content of the list to be below and not visible/accessible. It's also evident looking at the scrollbar siting below the added content.

The rootview of the ViewStub is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: I solved my problem switching from ViewStub to an include with visibility gone, and changing it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ordering of your items so that your ViewStub is positioned first, then the ListView  set to above your ViewStub:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      ...

    </TableRow>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/includeIdForPlayerStub"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/playerStubId"
        android:layout="@layout/player_stub" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/includeIdForPlayerStub"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableRow2">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did that and the result is a listView that sits on top of my "ViewStub". I can see it's contents when scrolling the listView, but the ViewStub is overlaid by the rows of the listView.